# WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe unexpectedly exited using DesiredCapabilities through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, desiredcapabilities

I need to use the most recent version of firefox on my Windows Computer. Hence dont want to use the default ghecko driver. Here is how close I got.

```
 import time
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
 from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

 binary = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
 caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()

 caps['marionette'] = True

 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,capabilities=caps, executable_path=(os.path.abspath("geckodriver.exe")))

 time.sleep(5)
 driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

The latest browser launches with default page however  `driver.get()` doesnt work while exiting with a WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1. How do I get around.

Comment: It seems like your firefox is crashing.  Does normal (non-automated) navigation work?

Comment: Yes it does. Im using it at the same time. You recommend I refresh ?

Comment: While I'm not an expert with firefox, you could try running your script without having it already running at the same time. It does seem that this can cause problems per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999922/selenium-firefox-is-already-running-error)

Comment: Following your advise it launches the default page but neither navigates away nor gives any error.

Comment: This could be a firewall issue, do you have any firewalls enabled? If so, try disabling them and retrying the script.

Comment: Okay let me try that as Ive just tried with Chrome as well and ended up with a status code of 0

Comment: No luck still stuck , firefox exit code 1 chrome exit code 0

Comment: Well, given that chrome exits with 0, it is likely something with Firefox then, but beyond that I have no other ideas.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I tried on a completely different computer same results

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of a couple of things here:

- The argument `executable_path` is used to pass the *absolute path* of the **geckodriver** binary.
- If *Firefox* is installed at the *default location* you don't have to pass the *absolute path* of the **firefox** binary at all.
- If you are using *Selenium 3.x*, *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox*, the capability **marionette** is set to **`true`** by default you don't have to explicitly mention that.
- Inducing `time.sleep()` degrades the *Test Execution Performance* use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) instead.
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
  options = Options()
  options.binary = binary
  cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX.copy()
  cap["marionette"] = True #optional
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  print ("Firefox Initialized")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Firefox Initialized
  ```

Comment: Thanks , launches with the ghecko driver which Im not after

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal What you are after?

Comment: I want to launch Mozilla Firefox Browser and not the ghecko one.

Comment: If you are using _Selenium 3.x_ and **marionette** enabled _Modern Firefox_ browsers you have to mandatory use _GeckoDriver_. In your code trials you have used it perfectly as in `executable_path=(os.path.abspath("geckodriver.exe")`.Are you looking for something else?

Comment: I want to launch the firefox Browser installed on my computer and not use ghecko. Thats what Im trying to acheive.

Comment: That's what I mentioned you **can't** and it is not _ghecko_ but _**gecko**_